# Vue and CSS3: absolute position in a relative wrapper messes up height

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am new to Vue and am learning the intricacies of CSS3

I am building a component which can be found here: https://codesandbox.io/s/yjp674ppxj

In short, I have a `ul` element with relative positioning and then a list of `div` elements with absolute positioning and I dynamically calculate the `top` property.

Ideally, I would like to have text appear after the entire list. However, by doing this, the `ul` element now has a height of `0px`. How can I preserve height and maintain the same effect?

below is a pure html5 & css3 MWE:

```css
ul {
  position: relative;
  border: solid 1px coral;
}

li {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(10px * var(--index));
  border: solid 0.5px black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li style="--index:0">list item</li>
<li style="--index:1">list item</li>
<li style="--index:2">list item</li>
<li style="--index:3">list item</li>
<li style="--index:4">list item</li>

</ul>

<p>test that shoudl be after list</p>
```

Comment: and why you need position:absolute?

Comment: @TemaniAfif for the positioning of the list elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `position:absolute` you can consider margin-top

```css
ul {
  position: relative;
  border: solid 1px coral;
  padding-top:8px;
}

li {
  margin-top: -8px;
  border: solid 0.5px black;
  transition:0.5s all;
}
li:hover {
  margin-top:-12px;
  margin-bottom:4px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>

</ul>

<p>test that shoudl be after list</p>
```

**UPDATE**

You can also consider transform on hover:

```css
ul {
  position: relative;
  border: solid 1px coral;
  padding-top:8px;
}

li {
  margin-top: -8px;
  border: solid 0.5px black;
  transition:0.5s all;
}
li:hover {
  transform:translateY(-5px);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>

</ul>

<p>test that shoudl be after list</p>
```

Comment: I like and dislike at the same time. Now it is important to pad the top of the list with the same amount as the shift... either way up vote for the solution. Let's wait a bit to see what others think of

Comment: @SumNeuron I don't think handling an extra padding is a big deal :) I think it's better than handling the height with a complicate code

Comment: @SumNeuron I added an update where you can handle the animation using transfrom instea

Comment: @Termani true, it isn't. Ideally, however, I am looking for a solution where I only have to define how much they should overlap (the margin-top / top).  The transform is a nice suggestion :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep `position: absolute` you can do the following:

Update your **ListPerspective.vue**:

```
  <ul class="mx-auto">
    <ListPerspectiveItem
      v-for="(alert, index) in alerts"
      :key="alert.id"
      :index="index"
      :alert="alert"
      :totalElements="alerts.length"
      :verticalShift="15"
      @close="remove(index)"
    />
    <div :style="notificationMsg"><slot></slot></div>
  </ul>
```

By adding a slotted list element at the end. Also add a computed style, i.e:

```
  data() {
    return { verticalShift: 15 }
  },
  computed: {
    notificationMsg() {
      return `position: absolute; top: ${(this.alerts.length + 1) * this.verticalShift}px; margin-top: 20px;`;
    }
  }
```

You calculate total distance from top of the component you need to display your message below notifications.

This unfortunately requires you to define `verticalShift` in your parent (ListPerspective) component and pass it as a prop to **ListPerspectiveItem**. If I were you I'd create a simple [store](https://vuex.vuejs.org/installation.html) with basic configs like these and instead of hardcoding `15` as a default value in your **ListPerspectiveItem** I'd fetch it from store, doing the same thing in **ListPerspective** component, i.e.:

```
data() { 
// generally you should bind store state properties as computed properties, 
// but since it's a default, constant variable you shouldn't have to watch for it's changes
  return { verticalShift: this.$store.state.defaults.css.verticalShift }
}


verticalShift: {
  type: Number, default: this.$store.state.defaults.css.verticalShift
}
```

Last thing left to do is to update your **App.vue** by adding your message to the slot:

```
  <ListPerspective>
      Click the &times; button to remove a message
  </ListPerspective>
```

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/ymxqq9mk11)

Comment: I wouldn't add the slot... the component is just the perspective list so I would just add a padding div if anything and let the text that follows be part of a larger app if needed. The store is a fair point, but neglected in the demo case to avoid another dependency.